# When can Javascript start calling Actionscript?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, prototype, swfobject

**Question**

Is there a non-polling way for Javascript to command Flash right when its external interface is ready?

**Background**

In Actionscript, I've registered a function for Javascript to call:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('doStuff", this.doStuff);
```

I use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) to embed the Flash into my page:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
    'flash/player.swf',
    'flashPlayer',
    '100%',
    '100%',
    '9',
    'expressInstallSwfTODO.swf',
    {},
    {allowfullscreen: true},
    {},
    function(status) {
        if (!status.success) {
            alert('Failed to embed Flash player');
        } else {
            $('flashPlayer').doStuff();
        }
    }.bind(this)
);
```

SWFObject lets you run code when Flash has been successfully embedded through a callback. I attempt to run $('flashPlayer').doStuff in this callback, but it claims it's undefined. It seems that Flash needs some time to boot up its external interface. So I've been using a polling hack to find out when the external interface is ready:

```
new PeriodicalExecutuer(
 function(poller) {
  if ($('flashPlayer').doStuff) {
   $('flashPlayer').doStuff();
   poller.stop()
  }
 },
 0.2
);
```

This poller is not ideal. There's a visually perceptible delay in the execution of doStuff and it makes my overall code structure muddy.

Comment: onload would be smoother but slower. Take your pick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript:

```
function flashIsReady()
{
    $('flashPlayer').doStuff();
}
```

In Actionscript:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.addCallback('doStuff', this.doStuff);
    ExternalInterface.call("flashIsReady");
}
```

Comment: And what if ExternalInterface is not available when this AS is run?

Comment: [ExternalInterface.available](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#available) says "Indicates whether this player is in a container that offers an external interface". I believe this means if it is false it will always be false in that browser so there's no point in checking again.

Answer (score 0):

I did a polling solution. In actionscript I have a function like this:

```
private function extIsInterfaceReady():Boolean {
    return ExternalInterface.available;
}
```

And in javascript, after the 'onFlashReady' event I also have coded into intialization, I start an interval like this:

```
  this.poll_flash = setInterval( function() {
    if ( typeof this.flash_obj === 'undefined' ) {
      return false;
    }

    if ( typeof this.flash_obj.isInterfaceReady === 'undefined' ) {
      return false;
    }

    if ( this.flash_obj.isInterfaceReady() ) {
      clearInterval(this.poll_flash);
      return this.continueOn();
    }
  }, 100);
```