# Flash does not receive resize event

Tags: javascript, flash, resize

In a div, we use swfobject to embed a flash player.  We wrote the flash player in action script. During the initialization of the web page, we use javascript to resize the div to make the player best fits the browser.  The enclosed flash player registers an OnResize event listener and handler.  The question is the OnResize event is not called when the enclosing div's resized.  (The OnResize event does get called when we drag to resize the browser afterwards.)   Could the be caused by the Flash VM is not fully ready when the div's being resized?  what is the best way to make sure the OnResize event is called in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To establish whether the events are firing in the order you expect, log them all to your JS console. Log the DIV resize from JS using `console.log` with Firebug/Chrome Dev, and log the Flash event firing using an ExternalInterface wrapper around the same `console.log`.

In Flash, `onAddedToStage` will be fired when your Flash is ready. I usually manually fire `onResize` in the `onAddedToStage` handler, in case the window was resized before the Flash was ready. You can also have your JS resize handler defer firing `onResize` on the Flash until after `onAddedToStage` is fired if you ensure that `onAddedToStage` is published to JS using ExternalInterface.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. I also saw this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771379/when-can-javascript-start-calling-actionscript.  so what event happens first, ExternalInterface's ready and onAddedToStage? thanks.

Comment: You mean `ExternalInterface.available`? I don't think there is an "ExternalInterface ready", per the docs. The problem with `available` is that you have to poll it. Furthermore, `available` being true, in my experiments, simply indicates that `ADDED_TO_STAGE` has fired, provided ExternalInterface is initialized in the stage setup.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I tried to use the AddedToStage event but somehow it's not working.  It's strange.  Maybe it's because i'm not in controller of the object that's being added to the stage.  What i have is that i'm integrating with good ad sense ads. I created an AdsLoader added it to stage but somehow the AddedToStage handler is not called.  I'm okay since i ended not relying on this event.